# Issue with both red and blue colors with validator and errorString of textinput

Tags: apache-flex, validation, textinput

I'm facing a strange issue with flex and validator.

Here is the code:

#### TestMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.validators.StringValidator;

        import utils.ValidableProperty;

        [Bindable] public var nameID:ValidableProperty;

        public function start():void {
            var nameIDValidator:StringValidator = new StringValidator();
            nameIDValidator.required = true;
            nameIDValidator.maxLength = 35;
            nameID = new ValidableProperty(nameIDValidator);
            nameID.validate();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:applicationComplete>
    start();
</s:applicationComplete>

<s:minHeight>600</s:minHeight>
<s:minWidth>955</s:minWidth>

<mx:Form color="0x323232" paddingTop="0">
    <s:Label text="See strange behavior of errorString during validator operation with validate."/>
    <mx:FormItem label="Name">
        <mx:TextInput id="nameInput" width="300" errorString="@{nameID.errorMessage}" text="@{nameID.value}"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

#### ValidableProperty.as

```
package utils
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent;
    import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
    import mx.validators.Validator;

    public class ValidableProperty extends EventDispatcher
    {
        [Bindable]
        public var value:Object;

        private var validator:Validator;

        [Bindable]
        public var isValid:Boolean;

        [Bindable]
        public var errorMessage:String;

        private var statusChangeHandler:Function;

        public function ValidableProperty(validator:Validator, statusChangeHandler:Function=null,
                                          target:IEventDispatcher=null) {
            super(target);

            this.validator = validator;
            this.statusChangeHandler = statusChangeHandler;

            this.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, propertyChangeHandler);
        }

        private function propertyChangeHandler(evt:PropertyChangeEvent):void {
            if (evt.property == "value") {
                this.validate();
            }
        }

        public function validate():void {
            var result:ValidationResultEvent = this.validator.validate(this.value);
            this.isValid = (result.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID);
            if (isValid) {
                this.errorMessage = null; 
            }
            else {
                this.errorMessage = result.message;
            }
            if (statusChangeHandler != null)
                statusChangeHandler();
        }

        public function set required(required:Boolean):void {
            if (validator == null)
                return;
            validator.required = required;
        }
    }
}
```

When you execute this simple code, when writing a value, for example "A", the errorMessage value "this field is required" will disappear but the red color on the inputtext border will still be there with the blue color.

When deleting the A value, this time the blue color will be there with the red one (cannot reproduce all the time) and the error message "this field is required".

What am I missing here? Is it a bug in flex? We cannot have both of red and blue colors on the textinput border.

I am using Eclipse with Flex SDK 4.5.0 (build 20967)

Comment: Why would you validate on application start? Also, why not put the validator in mxml?  and third, if you're using Spark already, why not use the Spark form? I also don't understand the point of doing double binding and trying to validate on the model and not the view... Have you tried the examples given in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in Flex.  This is a bug with how you're coding it all.  If you were to follow the [example in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/StringValidator.html), it would work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Simple example to demonstrate StringValidator. -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:StringValidator source="{nameInput}" property="text" 
                tooShortError="This string is shorter than the minimum length of 4. " 
                tooLongError="This string is longer than the maximum allowed length of 35." 
                minLength="4" maxLength="35"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

<s:Form>
    <s:FormItem label="Name">
        <s:TextInput id="nameInput" width="300" text="{nameID.value}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I provided a simple example to reproduce my error. Actually i use MVC
I can't use directly StringValidator because I use other kinds of validators. That's why I define ValidableProperty.
I tried to follow [link]http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=validators_5.html "Showing a validation error by using errorString" but reset seems to not work properly.
From my point it's not the view's job to enable or disable error message, that's why I use double binding. Each  time value is modified, validator will re-validate my textinput and update error.

Comment: This implementation works on other StringValidator from my project but for some it does not and I can't find a reason why...

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with this.  You're trying to validate the user input, not the data you get from your model.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve this. I was using mx:TextInput instead of s:TextInput. Thanks J_A_X for your suggestion !